# Automate Excel Reports from Mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, excel, automation

I currently work for a small start up, We have a MySQL database. My boss wants certain reports on a consistent basis and I'm trying to figure out how to automate these reports so they are created every few days. My boss likes to see the reports in excel format.

I have been doing research and came across MySQL for excel. I am using excel 2013.

My first question is

is MySQL to excel to best tool for the job?

I tried downloading MySQL for excel but it told me to install visual studio tool runtime, where do I get this install?

any guidance would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can run this query using a script to create .csv file which is alternate for xls you can open this file in xls and rename it.

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM Table;
```

Then rename the file .csv to xls.

or

https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/import/
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/exporting-and-importing-data-between-mysql-and-microsoft-excel.php